# Nested urls in Rails causes images routing problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, url, routes, nested

I have a rails 3 project where boards has_many topics. I'm trying to add a banner image by rendering a header partial:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Forum</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>
<%= render :partial => "layouts/header" %>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my header:

```
<div id="top">
<img src = '../public/images/cspill_banner.gif' style="height: 300px"/>
<div>
```

But when I go to this link http://localhost:3000/boards/1/topics/1 for some reason my image link is broken. When I follow the url I see that Rails is trying to access boards/1/images instead of /public/images:

```
Routing Error

No route matches "/boards/1/images/cspill_banner.gif"
```

Why is this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Rails `image_tag` helper:

For example:

```
<%= image_tag 'cspill_banner.gif', :style => 'height:300px' />
```

Comment: Thanks! while I still don't know exactly what's going on with Rails... it works.